# How do I use the UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, user-controls

1. Developer Environment

   - Tools : Visual Studio 2017
   - Language: C# - Windows Form
2. Create UserControl

   - testNext Property is Generic Type

   // ------- testControl.Designer.cs --------------------------------------

   ```
   partial class testTextBox<T>
   {
       private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
       protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           if (disposing && (components != null))
           {
               components.Dispose();
           }
           base.Dispose(disposing);
       }
       private void InitializeComponent()
       {
           this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
           this.SuspendLayout();
           // textBox1
           this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 2);
           this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
           this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(147, 21);
           this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
           this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.testTextBox_KeyPress);
           // testTextBox
           this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 12F);
           this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
           this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
           this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
           this.Name = "testTextBox";
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(157, 26);
           this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.testTextBox_Resize);
           this.ResumeLayout(false);
           this.PerformLayout();
       }            
       private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
   }
   ```

   // ------- testControl.cs ----------------------------------------------------

   ```
   public partial class testTextBox<T> : UserControl
   {
       public delegate void DelegateKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e);
       public event DelegateKeyPress testKeyPress;  
       public testTextBox()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
       public T _testNext;  // Generic property
       public T testNext
       {
           get
           {
               return this._testNext;
           }
           set
           {
               this._testNext = value;
           }
       }
       private void testTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
       {
           if (this._testNext != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(this._testNext.GetType().Name);
           }
           if (this.testKeyPress != null)
           {
               this.testKeyPress(sender, e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Using testTextBox

   - I want to use testTextBox in a form, but I can not use it in Design Mode
     How do I use the testTextBox?

Comment: How did you add usercontrol to your form

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure usercontrol and mainform have same namespace.

2. Build Solution
3. Double Click testControl.cs for open Design window.
4. Go to toolbox, and find  ** Comopnets ( ** is your project name )
5. your usercontrol is in there. just add and use.

Comment: Thank you answer
 ● 1. Generic Property Modified for testControl.cs ● 
    public T _testNext -> public string _testNext
 ● 2. UserControl Build

 ● 3. Open a form in another project -> Form Design Mode

 ● 4. Find UserControl dll(ex. testTextBox.dll) to Drag & Drop Toolbox

 ● 5. Very Nice
 ● But testControl.cs Change back
 ●     public string _testNext -> public T _testNext
 ● Build succeeds but is not added to Toolbox in new project
 ● The problem is how to use it in other projects when using Generic Property